# How to solve name conflict between member property and class name

Tags: c#

We call from static a member method of Class1 a static method of a Class2

```
public partial class Class1
{
  ...
  public static Class1Method()
  {
     Class2.StaticClass2Method();
  }
}
```

Due to a (generated) update Class1 has now a property called "Class2". We now get the compile error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property. How to solve this without renaming?

Comment: What namespace(s) are `Class1` and `Class2` in?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the full namespace of the Class2 class? You could try changing your call to `namespace.of.static.class.Class2.StaticClass2Method();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be fully referenced by namespace.  Examples:

```
MyNamespace.Class1 // = Class1
MyNamespace.Class2 // = Class2
MyNamespace.Class1.Class2 // = the property called Class2 inside Class1
```